# Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Unable to load template 'file:error_page.tpl'

Tags: php

I am using sqlmaestro PHP generator for MySQL version 20.5.0.4 to generate a web page that help me to communicate with a Database but this error keeps showing

Warning: Undefined property: Smarty_Internal_Undefined::$objMap in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\libs\smartylibs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_extension_handler.php on line 132

Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Unable to load template 'file:error_page.tpl' <-- thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\libs\smartylibs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_template.php on line 196

this is the first 196 lines of the smarty_internal_template.php :

```
   $_cache_id         cache   id or null<?php
/**
 * Smarty Internal Plugin Template
 * This file contains the Smarty template engine
 *
 * @package    Smarty
 * @subpackage Template
 * @author     Uwe Tews
 */

/**
 * Main class with template data structures and methods
 *
 * @package    Smarty
 * @subpackage Template
 *
 * @property Smarty_Template_Compiled             $compiled
 * @property Smarty_Template_Cached               $cached
 * @property Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase $compiler
 * @property mixed|\Smarty_Template_Cached        registered_plugins
 *
 * The following methods will be dynamically loaded by the extension handler when they are called.
 * They are located in a corresponding Smarty_Internal_Method_xxxx class
 *
 * @method bool mustCompile()
 */
#[\AllowDynamicProperties]
class Smarty_Internal_Template extends Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase
{
    /**
     * Template object cache
     *
     * @var Smarty_Internal_Template[]
     */
    public static $tplObjCache = array();

    /**
     * Template object cache for Smarty::isCached() === true
     *
     * @var Smarty_Internal_Template[]
     */
    public static $isCacheTplObj = array();

    /**
     * Sub template Info Cache
     * - index name
     * - value use count
     *
     * @var int[]
     */
    public static $subTplInfo = array();

    /**
     * This object type (Smarty = 1, template = 2, data = 4)
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $_objType = 2;

    /**
     * Global smarty instance
     *
     * @var Smarty
     */
    public $smarty = null;

    /**
     * Source instance
     *
     * @var Smarty_Template_Source|Smarty_Template_Config
     */
    public $source = null;

    /**
     * Inheritance runtime extension
     *
     * @var Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance
     */
    public $inheritance = null;

    /**
     * Template resource
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $template_resource = null;

    /**
     * flag if compiled template is invalid and must be (re)compiled
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $mustCompile = null;

    /**
     * Template Id
     *
     * @var null|string
     */
    public $templateId = null;

    /**
     * Scope in which variables shall be assigned
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $scope = 0;

    /**
     * Flag which is set while rending a cache file
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $isRenderingCache = false;

    /**
     * Callbacks called before rendering template
     *
     * @var callback[]
     */
    public $startRenderCallbacks = array();

    /**
     * Callbacks called after rendering template
     *
     * @var callback[]
     */
    public $endRenderCallbacks = array();

    /**
     * Create template data object
     * Some of the global Smarty settings copied to template scope
     * It load the required template resources and caching plugins
     *
     * @param string                                                       $template_resource template resource string
     * @param Smarty                                                       $smarty            Smarty instance
     * @param null|\Smarty_Internal_Template|\Smarty|\Smarty_Internal_Data $_parent           back pointer to parent
     *                                                                                        object with variables or
     *                                                                                        null
     * @param mixed                                                     
     * @param mixed                                                        $_compile_id       compile id or null
     * @param bool|int|null                                                $_caching          use caching?
     * @param int|null                                                     $_cache_lifetime   cache life-time in
     *                                                                                        seconds
     * @param bool                                                         $_isConfig
     *
     * @throws \SmartyException
     */
    public function __construct(
        $template_resource,
        Smarty $smarty,
        Smarty_Internal_Data $_parent = null,
        $_cache_id = null,
        $_compile_id = null,
        $_caching = null,
        $_cache_lifetime = null,
        $_isConfig = false
    ) {
        $this->smarty = $smarty;
        // Smarty parameter
        $this->cache_id = $_cache_id === null ? $this->smarty->cache_id : $_cache_id;
        $this->compile_id = $_compile_id === null ? $this->smarty->compile_id : $_compile_id;
        $this->caching = (int)($_caching === null ? $this->smarty->caching : $_caching);
        $this->cache_lifetime = $_cache_lifetime === null ? $this->smarty->cache_lifetime : $_cache_lifetime;
        $this->compile_check = (int)$smarty->compile_check;
        $this->parent = $_parent;
        // Template resource
        $this->template_resource = $template_resource;
        $this->source = $_isConfig ? Smarty_Template_Config::load($this) : Smarty_Template_Source::load($this);
        parent::__construct();
        if ($smarty->security_policy && method_exists($smarty->security_policy, 'registerCallBacks')) {
            $smarty->security_policy->registerCallBacks($this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * render template
     *
     * @param bool      $no_output_filter if true do not run output filter
     * @param null|bool $display          true: display, false: fetch null: sub-template
     *
     * @return string
     * @throws \Exception
     * @throws \SmartyException
     */
    public function render($no_output_filter = true, $display = null)
    {
        if ($this->smarty->debugging) {
            if (!isset($this->smarty->_debug)) {
                $this->smarty->_debug = new Smarty_Internal_Debug();
            }
            $this->smarty->_debug->start_template($this, $display);
        }
        // checks if template exists
        if (!$this->source->exists) {
            throw new SmartyException(
                "Unable to load template '{$this->source->type}:{$this->source->name}'" .
                ($this->_isSubTpl() ? " in '{$this->parent->template_resource}'" : '')
            );
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.